# iOs Custom Keyboard Layout not showing up

Tags: ios, xcode, custom-keyboard

I created a custom keyboard for iOs. It works well on my simulators and also on my own phone (that I used for testing), and so I published to the Appstore. When downloading from the app store it still works fine on my phone but not on other devices or not on other peoples devices.

For these other devices it doesn't even show up as an option in settings (when I click add new keyboard it doesn't show mine as a possibility?)

What could the problem be?